# OOP Composition over inheritance unwanted flexibility

Tags: oop, inheritance, composition

A problem I encountered a while ago when the flexibility provided by composition seemed like the wrong solution compared to inheritance - yet I am not sure which is better. I will be using C# for the examples but relevant to all OOP based languages.

Let's assume I have a class `Car` which has a property `Engine` and `Type`.
`Type` is an enum that can be `Honda`, `Mercedes`, etc...
`Engine` is an abstract class with some implementations.

The most straightforward approach to model it will be:

```
class Car
{
    public CarType Type { get; set; }

    public Engine Engine { get; set; }
}
```

Now we have the flexibility to provide each car a different engine (in runtime too) and a type. We can make any combination we want.

Now lets assume I have a different business rule:
`Honda` car **must** have engine of type `EngineX` **only**. The same applies to all car types - each with some specific engine (no flexibility needed by design).
There are two ways to tackle it:

1. Same model as we have and the business rule will be enforced at runtime (or never enforced)
2. Create a new class called `HondaCar` which inherits from `Car` with engine set specifically to `EngineX`. `Car` will now become an empty base class.

Let's say we took the second approach - if a few different cars have the same engine we are duplicating code.
In addition if a car has no engine (let's assume it can happen) the second approach allows me to omit the engine property while in the first I need to assign null as the engine. It can be solved with another class in the hierarchy chain called `EngineXCar` but I am not sure its a good idea.

So the question is - while composition with a single class requires less changes when adding new cars we gain flexibility which in some cases is a good idea while in this case it only makes the model very error prone. Is it a valid case to create specific car classes? Even if there are say 30 types of cars? What about the model duplications created in this way? Is it a valid "payment"?

Comment: I'd approach this in a data-driven way. Maximum flexibility with constraints enforced at runtime. The implementation will be identical for all cases and constraints would be easy to modify and make exceptions if needed. My intuition is that nothing really prevents `Honda` from having any engine, as long is provides the necessary interface. (This situation is asking for some engine compatibility database). The question would be different if the engines for `Honda` required some functionality that is specific to it. If a car can have no engine then `Optional` seems suitable.

Comment: Also, perhaps the properties that make the engine compatibile with a given car model or not can be abstracted away?

Comment: @Sopel `Honda` must have a specific engine - it's tightly coupled. Which means I will do at some point `(hondaCar.Engine as EngineX).Whatever` in the first approach. But anyway if I need to always update the validation what's the difference from the classes approach? Only that it will fail in runtime and will be tougher to find. What's more I can have something called `HondaEngine` which by design coupled to `Honda`. It looks weird that I can create a `Mercedes` car with a `HondaEngine` and it will only fail at runtime at some unknown point.